# Is there a way to quickly "man" pre-defined struct in c in terminal?

Tags: c, terminal, manpage

I am not an expert in c programming. 
What I did now is google every struct or function that I am not familiar with and see their usage.  However "man" in terminal is a lot more handy and way faster. But I can only "man" to check for functions, is there a way to also refer to information on those structures defined in different libraries by typing some command in terminal.  I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ctags`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) to index structs, variables, or C++ classes, methods, etc from all of your header files in `/usr/include` or other directories. The result is a text file that can then be used by `vim` to jump to the definition of the struct. Some other editors also support this index (or tag) file.

Comment: I have brewed ctags and tried run [this command](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Generate_ctags_file_for_a_C/C%2B%2B_source_file_with_all_of_their_dependencies_%28standard_headers,_etc%29) in my project, I can now refer to all the functions defined in .h files in my project.  But I still don't know how to make it compile a tag file to generate all those standard library files I included in any of the source files in my project.  any guide ?

Comment: Which command you tried? It should be similar for both local project and standard library files. Try with this command: `ctags -R -V --totals -f usr-include.tags /usr/include` .